# Get Health data on WearOs watch, not on phone

Tags: wear-os, sensors, temperature, heartrate, healthconnect

I am creating an app for Samsung watch 6 which is using WearOS. I want to show following health data directly from the watch, independent of it being connected to any phone.

- Heart Rate
- SPO2
- BloodPressure
- Body Temperature
- Steps
- Sleep

I found a sample app for HearRate called [MeasureDataCompose](https://github.com/android/health-samples/tree/main/health-services/MeasureDataCompose). This works fine for Heart Rate, I want to get all above data. The sample code is either not intuitive that I could get the data above, or there is something I dont understand.
I could not find any help on this, which is very disappointing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Health Services on Wear OS is an API that will allow you to get sensor data from any device running Wear OS 3 or higher. This is the API the sample you linked uses.

You can reference this page to learn about the [3 clients](https://developer.android.com/health-and-fitness/guides/health-services#create-apps) offered. Just as a quick overview:

- The sample app linked uses `MeasureClient`, which is suitable for instantaneous/spot measurement. You can [query the capabilities](https://developer.android.com/health-and-fitness/guides/health-services/active-data/measure-client#check-capabilities) to understand which metrics are supported for spot measurement on your device.
- You can use `PassiveMonitoringClient` to monitor steps in the background throughout the day. You can also monitor both steps and HR as part of an active exercise (`ExerciseClient`).
- You can also use Health Services to monitor [`UserActivityState`](https://developer.android.com/health-and-fitness/guides/health-services/monitor-background#useractivityinfo), which will tell you if a user is awake or has fallen asleep. Beyond this, there isn't a standardized way to measure sleep stages on Wear OS.

For the other metrics mentioned, you may want to look into the [Samsung Privileged Health SDK](https://developer.samsung.com/health/privileged/overview.html) if you are developing with a Galaxy Watch. This will enable you to get SPO2, Body Temperature, and access to PPG sensors.

Comment: Thanks. This "Samsung Privileged Health SDK" is not free, right?

Comment: @Brena There has to be an alternate SDK for all this data, right?

Comment: You could look into SensorManager (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor) and use getSensorList to see what is available. Not sure about costs associated with the Privileged Health SDK, though it does require filling out a form to request access.